# A tricky integration problem

Tags: calculus

Given: $$f(x)=\int_{x}^{0}\frac{\cos(xt)}t\, dt.$$ What is $f'(x)?$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: It's not as simple as that. There is no way to separate cos(xt)! I tried to substitute xt by u, in the integrand, so that $f(x)=F(0)-F(x^2)$. But the result is still wrong

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit this seems to be what I'm looking for

Comment: @MichaelBurr Ok so does this mean that FTOC trick no longer applicable for indefinite integral?

Comment: I miswrote and meant improper (it's been a long day).  See my answer below.

Comment: If it were say $f(x) = \int_x^1 \frac{\cos(xt)}{t} \, dt$, $x > 0$, you could solve this using the multivariate chain rule: let $g(x,y) := \int_x^1 \frac{\cos(yt)}{t}\,dt$.  Then $f(x) = g(x,x)$; $g_x(x,y)$ can be calculated using FTC; and $g_y(x,y) = - \int_x^1 \sin(yt)\, dt$.

Comment: @ Is $a$ a variable or constant or both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an improper integral, as $t$ approaches $0$, the numerator approaches $1$ while the denominator approaches $0$.

You must check that the limit doesn't diverge!
$$
f(x)=\lim_{c\rightarrow 0^{\pm}}\int_x^c\frac{\cos(xt)}{t}dt
$$
where you use $\pm$ on $0$ depending on the sign of $x$.

Therefore, near $0$, you're integrating something like $\int_0^\varepsilon\frac{dt}{t}$.

This, however, diverges, so $f(x)$ diverges.  How do you take a derivative?

Comment: But are you saying there is no answer to this question?

Comment: It seems to be so.  Try asking wolfram alpha to compute some of the integrals for various $x$, you'll keep getting does not converge.

Comment: There is actually a solution given by the book using Leibniz integration rule. But it seems to be erroneously ignoring one term in the formula, upon closer inspection. Spend one hour on this thing!!  Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Well, you can get an "answer" using Leibniz integration rule, it would look like $\int_x^0\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\cos(xt)}{t}dt-\frac{\cos(x^2)}{x}+\frac{\cos(0\cdot x)}{0}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}0$, but this doesn't look so good ...

Comment: Exactly, the book assumed that the last term equals to 0. But for those who are watching, Leibniz integration is not really applicable here upon checking required conditions: partial derivative w.r.t. x is not continuous on the closed set [0,x].